# Is there an equivalent probability distribution for fermions and bosons to the expression for distinguishable particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

So the particle distribution of two particles is simply

$$ P_{12}=P_1(r_1)P_2(r_2) $$

where $ P_{12}$ is simply the modulus of the total wavefunction squared and $ P_1 $  and $ P_2$ are the the individual particle distributions.
Obviously, this doesn't apply to fermions and bosons whose wavefunctions have symmetry requirements. I was wondering if anyone had an equivalant expression for fermions or bosons?

Answer (score 1):

The wave function for a pair of *independent*, indistinguishable bosons/fermions with no internal degrees of freedom can be written in the position representation as
$$ \Psi(r_1,r_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\psi_1(r_1)\psi_2(r_2) \pm \psi_2(r_1)\psi_1(r_2) \right ].$$
You can calculate your desired probability distribution from $P_{12}(r_1,r_2) = \lvert\Psi(r_1,r_2)\rvert^2$. Clearly the outcome will not be a simple product, as you already anticipated. Furthermore, the (anti-)symmetry will enhance (suppress) the probability that the particles co-exist at the same location $P_{12}(r,r)$ for bosons (fermions).